# How can I work with a huge csv file that does not fit in the RAM with a combination of Power Query and Power Pivot on Excel 2010

Tags: excel, powerpivot, powerquery

I wonder if someone can help me with the following problem. First off my setup (which I can't change because it is a corporate environment)

- Operating system: Windows 7 Professional. Service Pack 1. 32bit
- Hardware: 8.00 GB RAM (2.73 Gb usable)

I am looking for a solution for slicing and dicing really big files (around 5Gb) with Excel. So the equivalent of being able to use pivot tables and graphs with so much data.

I just got Power Query and Power Pivot installed on my laptop (remember I'm running Excel 2010 - 32bit) and saved the huge .csv file as a connection with Power Query. However, I can't add it to my data model and use it from Power Pivot (apparently that is a problem in Excel 2010). I tried to get around by clicking on Power Pivot -> existing connections. But then it tries to import everything and I run out of memory or hit some Excel limit.

To me, the idea should be that the data is never loaded, that it is kept as a connection (where you only store the query) and that data is loaded "lazily" and only what you need after you set up the Power Pivot report (otherwise I don't know how Power Query and Power Pivot help to work with big files that wouldn't fit in Excel otherwise).

What can I do to add the connection to the huge file to the data model so that I can continue working until I can set up a report (with Power Pivot) and see the results?

If there is a software package I am missing (such as Power BI), that would help me fix the problem please let me know. If it's free (like Power Query and Power Pivot) I could have it installed.

Thank you very much in advance and regards

Comment: Did you try Power BI?

Comment: I did not. Is it free even for companies? If that would solve the problem, I wouldn't mind going through the pain of having another software package installed in the corporate environment

Comment: It's free as long as you don't want to share to others online. As a desktop tool it's definitely free. You may have issues with your 32 bit OS though. It's more about visualisation than tables and grids though. It's free to download and you should be able to install without admin access. Download from the microsoft app store

Comment: Good to know that it is free for companies too. I don't know if it will solve my problem, though. I've used it at home and it's good for dashboards, but the problem I want to get around is related to size. I want a tool so that I can set up the reports (with numbers and plots) with huge data sources and the tool should be smart enough never to load all the data in memory or in the Excel file. It should load to memory only what is needed and when is needed (I thought Power Pivot and Power Query were the right tools for that, maybe I was wrong)

Comment: You could always try SQL Express (free) or you could try analytics on Azure (free account available)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but Azure is out of the question (No cloud solution as I'm speaking about a highly regulated corporate environment). I can only use a desktop application. I will see if I can work with power BI but I will have to wait for one week until I get it installed :(

Comment: Note that for Power BI desktop, since you are on window's 7 updating it for any of the monthly updates requires admin access.

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like the loading the CSV directly into power pivot failed due to importing everything.  One option would be loading the CSV into an intermediary database like an access file (or SQL server Express) while cleaning up the data to improve memory usage.

Note: power pivot uses more memory when it is updating the model.

[Link to Creating an memory efficient model](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-memory-efficient-Data-Model-using-Excel-and-the-Power-Pivot-add-in-951c73a9-21c4-46ab-9f5e-14a2833b6a70) which has some tips on how to design power pivot models to be more memory efficient.

Also note that uniqueness of data drastically effects how much data can fit in memory.  Columns with less distinct values consume less memory, something that is unique like a row_ID on a fact table would consume a ton of memory.

Comment: Thanks very much. I will get Access installed and do as you say, although I see no reason why it should get any better. My data is pretty clean already after the transform step of Power Query. If Power Pivot loads everything in memory for the data model, whether the data is coming from Access or a csv file, it shouldn't make a difference ... I would always run out of memory, isn't it?

Comment: Well it mainly depends on how many rows of data you are dealing with, and how repetitive it is.  For example I have loaded 16 M rows of retailer POS data into Power Pivot, but that would be an example of fairly repetitive data which I had structured to be as memory efficient as possible,